# If the legal 7th delivery is a no ball then will there be a free hit?

Tags: rules, cricket, icc

By legal 7th delivery, I mean the umpire not realising that 6 balls have been bowled and so the bowler throws the 7th delivery. I know that in such a case the extra ball is considered to legal.
But if this 7th delivery is a no ball and then the umpire realises that there has been a mistake in counting, does ICC allow a free hit to be given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laws of cricket would apply, in [Law 17.5](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-17-the-over/) if an umpire miscounts, they will call over even if the ball was not a legal delivery.

> **[Law 17 - The over](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-17-the-over/)**
>
> 17.5 Umpire miscounting
>
> 17.5.1 If the umpire miscounts the number of valid balls, the over as counted by the umpire shall stand.
>
> 17.5.2 If, having miscounted, the umpire allows an over to continue after 6 valid balls have been bowled, he/she may subsequently call Over when the ball becomes dead after any delivery, even if that delivery is not a valid ball.